# Ter o identificador numa linha da tabela

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Olá,

Eu estou a desenvolver uma aplicação web que contém uma lista com vários elementos. A minha ideia será que após um click sobre um dos elementos, ele abra uma nova página com os detalhes do elemento clicado. Para isso, neste momento, eu tenho que colocar algo que me identifique o elemento: `<div class="elem" data-id="2">`.

Neste momento, as linhas da minha lista estão a ser colocadas da seguinte forma (eu estou a utilizar .NET MVC):

```
@foreach (KnowAcquisitionParticipant participant in Model.Participants)
{
    <div class="famo-row famo-body-row" data-is-new-participant="no" data-id="@participant.Employee.ID">
        <div class="famo-cell famo-col-1">
            <select class="famo-input famo-text-10" name="participantID">
                <option value=""></option>
                @foreach (Employee employee in Model.Employees)
                {
                    <option value="@employee.ID" @(employee.ID == participant.Employee.ID ? "selected" : string.Empty)>@employee.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="famo-cell famo-col-2">
            <input type="text" class="famo-input famo-text-10" name="totalHours" value="@(participant.TotalHours.HasValue ? participant.TotalHours.Value.ToString() : string.Empty)" />
        </div>
        <div class="famo-cell famo-col-3">
            <input type="text" class="famo-input famo-text-10" name="activeHours" value="@(participant.ActiveHours.HasValue ? participant.ActiveHours.Value.ToString() : string.Empty)" />
        </div>
        <div class="famo-cell famo-col-4 text-center">
            <button type="button" class="famo-button famo-cancel-button button-delete-participant">
                <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Contudo, eu acho que facilmente alguem pode alterar o valor do `data-id` e fazer com que entre noutra página que não a que era suposta (eu tenho um processo que valida no servidor se o utilizador tem acesso ou não).

Estive a ver outros sites tipo o do Gmail ou o do Outlook.com e não me parece que tenham identificadores para os e-mails e mesmo quando parecem que tem, eu altero mas abre sempre o e-mail correto.

Como é que é possível?

Comment: Podes fazer isso de _N_ maneiras diferentes. Esse teu HTML é estático ou gerado com JavaScript? Podes colocar esse código e/ou o código que abre a outra página?

Comment: @Sergio Eu estou a utilizar .NET MVC com Razor Views, eu vou buscar a informação a uma API e depois com um ciclo for coloco-a no HTML

Comment: Esse ciclo for é JavaScript ou server side? Podes clicar em [edit] e colocar esse loop na pergunta?

Comment: @Sergio já editei a pergunta e já tem o ciclo. O ciclo é server side.

Comment: "outros sites tipo o do Gmail ou o do Outlook.com e não me parece que tenham identificadores para os e-mails" não é verdade. No Gmail cada email está num `<tr>`, exemplo retirado do inspecionar : `<tr class="zA yO x7" jsmodel="nXDxbd" id=":jjj" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby=":2u" draggable="true">`. Se reparar o `id=":jjj"` (que para exemplo eu troquei) é o identificador, e quando o troco deixo de conseguir abrir o email respetivo. Convido-o a fazer essa experiencia.

Comment: @Isac tem toda a razão, se alterar o `id=":jjj"` para outra coisa, o e-mail deixa de abrir mas os testes que fiz foi entre trocar os id's de dois e-mails para ver se ao clicar num abriria o outro mas não é isso que acontece

Comment: Está a dizer se trocar id`s de emails entre si, continua a abrir o mesmo e não o trocado é isso ?

Comment: @Isac Sim, é isso

Comment: Sim de facto isso acontece, o que significa que não se baseiam apenas no `id`. Tem de se estar a basear também noutras informações

Comment: Exatamente, eles devem de estar a utilizar outra verificação por trás. Eu gostaava de saber que tipo de verificação é que fazem.

Comment: Também fiquei intrigado agora, quando tiver um pouco de tempo vou ver se faço alguns testes para ver se descubro o que eles estão exatamente a fazer